# My navigation and footer are extending beyond the viewport width even though they are both set to 100%. What could I be doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I have tried just about everything I could find online. I have a header and footer each with two divs inside. When I set justify-content to space inbetween it pushes the right div out of the view port.

I tried adding box-sizing, changing the margins, setting max widths, and changing the CSS on the overall page. The code I have is below:

`

```
 <header class="main-navigation">
       <div class="logo">
           <object data="img/zain-surka.svg" width="130" height="64"> </object>
       </div>
       <nav>
          <ul class="links">
             <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">work</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">about</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-item">contact</a></li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
 </header>

<footer id="footer">
     <div class="contact">
                <div class="contact-item">
                    <object data="img/phone-icon.svg" width="16" height="16"> </object>
                    <a href="#">###.###.####</a>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-item">
                    <object data="img/mail-icon.svg" width="16" height="16"> </object>
                    <a href="#">email@gmail.com</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="socials">
                <object data="img/Instagram.svg" width="16" height="16" class="social-item"</object>
                <object data="img/Twitter.svg" width="16" height="16" class="social-item"> </object>
                <object data="img/LinkedIn.svg" width="16" height="16" class="social-item"> </object>
      </div>

        </footer>
```

```
/* navigation */

.main-navigation {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px 60px 30px 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.links {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 0.83333rem;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 0.83333rem;
}

.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    width: 8.64583rem;
    height: 1.3125rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* footer */

#footer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.9375rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box
        /* Footer height */

}

.contact {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.625rem;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1.5625rem;
    width: auto;
}

.contact-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: .5rem;
}



.socials {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    gap: 3rem;
}

.social-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the header element. By default, the `width` property specifies the content area of an element, and padding is added on top. Specifying `box-sizing: border-box` will subtract padding, borders and margin, so that the actual width of the element matches the `width`. You can find a good summary of this and further reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).

Comment: I’ve done this and it helps somewhat but the spacing is still not quite right. It keeps everything from overflowing off the page but the edge of the container isn’t right at the edge of the viewport.

Comment: `<body>` elements have a margin by default, which might be generating the space you're noticing. Try setting `margin: 0` on your body styles.